# Symfony2.1 form date field: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of DateTime

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

My Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime $publishedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="published_at", type="date")
 * 
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
private $publishedAt;

/**
 * Set publishedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $publishedAt
 * @return MagazineIssue
 */
public function setPublishedAt(\DateTime $publishedAt)
{
    $this->publishedAt = $publishedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get published_at
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getPublishedAt()
{
    return $this->publishedAt;
}
```

My form builder:

```
$builder->add('publishedAt');
```

My view:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

When I select the date in the selects and submit the form I catche the error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of DateTime, 
string given, called in .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form
/Util/PropertyPath.php on line 537 and defined in ... line 214
```

Why it happens? If I replace the field setter with `public function setPublishedAt($publishedAt)` I got the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object 
in .../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateType.php on line 44
```

If I change the form builder to

```
 $builder->add('publishedAt','date')
```

all works fine. Why it happens? Why symfony can't guess it and pass to field setter the proper date format (\DateTime instead of string)?

**EDIT:** if I remove the `@Assert\Date()` then all works fine too. I think it's a sf2.1 bug with guessing the date field type

Comment: the error is clear : you're trying to set a string instead of a datetime object, how did you render your publishedat field?

Comment: I described above, just `{{ form_widget(form) }}` and it render all fields of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you can

1.change the assert from `@Assert\Date()` to `@Assert\Type('\DateTime')`

OR

2.change the form builder to `$builder->add('publishedAt','date')`

OR

3.specify the `input` option in the form builder: `$builder->add('publishedAt',null,array('input' => 'datetime'))`

Comment: It's @Assert\DateTime() https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/DateTime.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 1):

I used to deal with this just like **Max** wrote but then I discovered **[Data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)**. It's very efficient way and does not imply modifications to model (or it's getter/setter methods)...

**EDIT:** Check out the title "Using Transformers in a custom field type". They write about `DateTime` there...

Comment: I don't understand why Sf can't guess it. If I change a form builder to `$builder->add('publishedAt','date')` all works fine. Do you know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine want to call \DateTime::format(). From a string.

You can check the argument in the setter method:

```
public function setPublishedAt($publishedAt)
{
    if($publishedAt instanceof \DateTime) {
        $this->publishedAt = $publishedAt;
    } else {
        $date = new \DateTime($publishedAt);
        $this->publishedAt = $date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood this. But it is not pretty way. I use a default documentation from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-a-simple-form) and it's doesn't work

Comment: DataTransformer will be needed here.