# Symfony form builder Add instance of \DateTime

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime

I'm trying since some of hour to add a \DateTime validation in a form builder

The Customer entity (Sample):

```
class Customer
{

     /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="date")
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthDate() : ? \DateTime
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $birthDate
     */
    public function setBirthDate(int $birthDate) : self
    {
        $this->birthDate = (new \DateTime())->setTimeStamp($birthDate);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The form builder is like this (Sample):

```
class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('birthDate', DateTimeType::class, ['data_class' => \DateTime::class]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Customer::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I want to submit the form, I received always a error:

The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class DateTime, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the \"data_class\" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of DateTime.

The user is sending the good parameter:

```
"customer": {
        "birthDate": 30459425029458,
    }
```

I tryed to follow this solution without success

[Symfony2.1 form date field: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970681/symfony2-1-form-date-field-argument-1-passed-to-must-be-an-instance-of-date)

And the view transformer return a null value

```
$builder->get('birthDate')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($tagsAsArray) {
                    // transform the array to a string
                    return implode(', ', $tagsAsArray);
                },
                function ($tagsAsString) {
                    // transform the string back to an array
                    return explode(', ', $tagsAsString);
                }
            ))
        ;
```

I tried to switch data-class option to null but the form send me a no valid value error.

How can I validate a instance of \DateTime in formBuilder?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Temporary bad solution:

```
if(isset($params['customer']['birthDate'])) {
            $customer->setBirthDate($params['customer']['birthDate']);
        } else {
            $this->error = ['message' => 'birthDate missing'];
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: why do you save the `$birthDay` as a timestamp (`int`) inside the `Customer` class? (instead of saving the `\DateTime` object directly)

Comment: Unfortunatly not, The user send a timestamp and we are converting to DateTime

Comment: I mean, why you don’t define the setter as `setBirthDate(\DateTime $birthDate)` and simply do `$this->birthDate = $birthDate;` inside it?

Comment: @MikO it's not the issue right here

Comment: Try with `@Assert\DateTime()` constraint instead?

Comment: Also use `'widget' => 'single_text',` option in your form type if you expects a single value.

Comment: @yceruto @Asset\DateTime() perform the validation for a html date picker and the 'widget' => 'single_text' need a string format, not the instance